# Efficient excel range index lookup

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, syntactic-sugar

The following VBA UDF is used extensively in a spreadsheet I have created. It is syntactic sugar.

```
Function o(r As Range, t As Long) As Double


    o = r.Cells(t - 2, 1)


End Function
```

I have given all my columns names, as named ranges. In a formula this enables me to refer to a cell in a different column just by using the column's name. The function above allows me to do the same, but referring to rows by an offset value.

for example if i have some enitre columns nameA and nameB, the formula:

```
= nameA + nameB
```

is valid.

with o() i can do things like

```
= o(name,1) + name
```

Is there are more efficient/elegant way to do this?

Comment: If your code is working and you are looking to simply discuss improvements etc, you might want to consider the following SE instead of this one:  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you're using your UDF like that, is the sole purpose to save some keystrokes? (Because `=Offset(cell,-1,0)` is only maybe 7 more keys)

Comment: It's not just keystrokes. It's more for readability. Is offset faster?